# Bootstrap modal autoresizing after first click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bunch of `div's` that are being displayed inside a `bootstrap modal` window which gets activated with a click of a button,

The problem is `whenever i refresh the page` and click on the button it `opens up fine` 
but when i close the modal dialog box and re-click the button the `div elements appear outside the modal window`

- This is the first time opening the modal dialog after i refresh the page
  [image: 1st modal dialog]
- This is the second time opening the modal dialog after i close the first one (the div elements are overflowed **outside the modal dialog box**)
  [image]

This is the code for my current modal-dialog

```
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="../Images/pix/place.png" href="#supket" data-toggle="modal" /></div><!-- calls the pop-up -->
    <div class = "modal fade" id="supket" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3>*** TITLE ****</h3> 
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="supkettt" runat="server"></div><br /><br /></div> <!-- content of the modal-dialog -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**P.S: I'm using bootstrap 3.0** and i have about 4 modal boxes and this is the only one that i have problem with.

Comment: Some code or a jsfiddle/bootply example?

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @devo updated with the codes.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xjgxc/ with your code and i can't see any problems, if you have more code in this model update there and post the updated fiddle link here.

Comment: @devo i tried it on multiple browsers as well, still the same. Will update it when i find a fix.

Comment: What is the content of the .modal-body?

Comment: @Skelly few buttons and texts that are got dynamically.

Comment: does your issue solved? are you using updatepanel? how u call modal? using registerclientscript?